# In MSVC 6, is an int 16 or 32 bits?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6

In MSVC 6, Windows, is an int 16 or 32 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its 4 bytes .  sizeof(int)) gives you the answer . Try it

Comment: I would try it, but I don't have the compiler. I'm just looking at some old code.

Comment: No worries mate .. I have one .Its 4 bytes for sure :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is 32, but you can check using `printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));` and multiplying the answer by 8.

Comment: I would, but I don't have the compiler. I'm just looking at some old code.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm, yes, it's 4 bytes. The last 16-bit version of VC++ was 1.52c. The next version after that was VC++ 2.0, which was available only in a 32-bit version.